# Execute successive batch file on inno setup

Tags: mysql, batch-file, inno-setup

I'm trying to execute successive batch file: 
The first is starting the installation of  Mysql
The second  is a batch script to execute sql script

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\install.bat"; Flags: shellexec waituntilterminated
Filename: "{app}\createBase.bat"; Flags: shellexec waituntilterminated
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: postinstall
```

The second line is not executed.

I also regroup the 2 batches files it doesn't work too:

```
  @echo off

       **(from the first batch)**

 start  /i /wait mysql-5.1.36-win32.msi
      **(the second batch)** 

"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysql" --default-character-set=utf8 -u root -proot < dbase.sql;
```

I think that I must change something on the last line (the Flags)

So anyone can help me Please?

Comment: And what is the intention of the third one ? Now the third entry shows the *"Execute your app"* check box at the finish page.

Comment: yes the third line is for executing the application. The second line is not executed

Comment: The `flags` of the last entry will have no effect on the other entries. Have you confirmed from `/log` that it isn't being run? Does that batch file work ok when run from the command prompt?

Comment: yes the second batch works fine but when I add the first batch for the installation of mysql this doesn't work

Comment: The best solution is to not try to use batch files in the first place.  Everything that you've shown there can be executed much more readily directly from the `[Run]` section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find how ; I regroup the 2 batch files on one this is also a silent installation of mysql + the configuration and the exution of a sql script ( all on one batch file):

```
 start /wait msiexec /i mysql-5.1.36-win32.msi /passive

"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqlinstanceconfig.exe" -i -q ServiceName=MySQL RootPassword=root ServerType=DEVELOPMENT    DatabaseType=MYISAM Port=3306 RootCurrentPassword=root"

"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysql" --default-character-set=utf8 -u root -proot < dbase.sql
```